# How to manipulate results of Mocha test in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have a simple Mocha file:

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Array', function () {
  describe('#indexOf()', function () {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function () {
      assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm looking to run the test above inside Node.js and get access to the test results for further manipulation.

I know it's possible to import Mocha and run tests, like this:

```
const Mocha = require('mocha');

const test = new Mocha();
test.addFile('./assert.js');
test.run();
```

But, I'd like a way of getting the result of `assert.equal` and the corresponding descriptions, perhaps via the `then()` method. Any ideas? Could `Sinon.JS` help?

The end goal is to display these tests in the browser, using an API endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the instance of `test` and look for events for each test execution.

for example:

```
const Mocha = require('mocha');

const test = new Mocha();
test.addFile('./assert.js');
let runner = test.run();

runner.on('pass', (e) => {
    passed.push({
        title: e.title,
        speed: e.speed,
        duration: e.duration,
        file: e.file
    });
});

runner.on('fail', (e) => {
    failed.push({
        title: e.title,
        err: error,
        file: e.file
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi hafridi, I'm getting the error `runner.on is not a function`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry wrong variable...In my mind I would have called it `runner` but you called it `test`

Comment: Also, the example assumes that you have two arrays declared, one for failed and one was passed. This will store the results.

Comment: Hmm, I've declared the arrays and changed the variable name and I'm still getting the same `test.on` error

Comment: here's a GitHub gist of my full file: https://gist.github.com/BretCameron/64796d7fb1f9b2e1d38ed5a977ce52d2

Comment: Updated. The snippet.

Comment: Ah, I missed `let runner = test.run();` - it's working now! Many thanks!